# Autocomplete term widget (tagging)

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

I was using the "autocomplete term widget (tagging)" as widget type for a term reference field. I found out that the when I set the maximum number of allowed values to more than one (i.e multiple choices), the auto complete does not work after you have added one option.

Do you have any idea on how to work around this?

Answer (score 4):

I too am using autocomplete for a term reference field and multiples are working fine - are you sure you're putting commas between terms? e.g. I type "one, t" and as I type "t", "two" will come up as a suggestion if the term is in the vocabulary.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with the "," symbol after each new word: It is working fine for me on IE 6 and Firefox 1.5.